# Orthogonally diagonalize matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

Find matrix P that orthogonally diagonalizes C.
$$
C= \begin{pmatrix} 
1&2&0\\2&1&0\\
0&0&5\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

I have worked through this problem by taking the eigenvectors and then normalizing the answer. The answer I get is

$$
P= \begin{pmatrix} 
-1/\sqrt2&1/\sqrt2&0\\1/\sqrt2&1/\sqrt2&0\\
0&0&1\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

My book though gives the following answer of

$$
P= \begin{pmatrix} 
1/\sqrt2&1/\sqrt2&0\\1/\sqrt2&-1/\sqrt2&0\\
0&0&1\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

The eigenvalues I got were $5,3,$and $-1$. The eigenvectors and normalization  I got were $(0,0,1)=(0,0,1)$
$(1,1,0)=(1/\sqrt2,1/\sqrt2,0)$ and $(-1,1,0)=(-1/\sqrt2,1/\sqrt2,0)$.

Which one is correct?, if any.

Comment: Why not compute $P^{-1}CP$ for both choices of $P$ to see what you get?

Comment: I get the same answer for both, the original matrix.

Comment: Why have you chosen to order your basis as $\{(0,0,1),(1,1,0),(-1,1,0)\}$ (well, the ON basis of this) and not any of the other ways? Would that change your matrix $P$? How? And does the ordering of the basis affect if $P$ can orthogonally diagonalise $C$?

Comment: Diagonalizing matrices are not unique, since you can modify the basis you want to get another basis (e.g., multiplying an eigenvector by $1$ or $-1$ will not change orthonormality). Here, it's a matter of the order in which you put the eigenvectors, and possibly multiplying an eigenvector by $-1$.

Comment: I’m not quite sure how the textbook got the y value to be negative and not the x-value.Unless they did multiply the eigenvector by -1, which seems unnecessary.

Comment: Which one is positive and which one negative depends on which one you take as leading and which one as dependent when you solve the corresponding system. You can easily get either solution. I would have gotten your textbook's, because of how I usually solve these systems. Six of one, half a dozen of the othet.